# Do not match YouTube URLs with beginning double quotes - C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I have the following C# regex

```
@"(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:(?:(?:youtube\.com\/watch\?[^?]*v=|youtu\.be\/)))([\w-]+)";
```

How can I correct this so the regex won't match URLs with double quote at the beginning of the URL. so if the URL is in an `href` attribute in an hyperlink, it will be ignored and not captured.

I've used this expression in my other Twitter Regex pattern, but I can't make it work in this one.

```
(?<!"")
```

It worked on the Twitter pattern:

```
(?<!"")https?://twitter\.com/(?:#!/)?(\w+)/status(?:es)?/(\d+)
```

So the YouTube Regex should grab only URLs that are not with double quotes in the beginning of the URL.

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%22%5b%5e%22%3c%3e%5d*%29%28%3f%3ahttps%3f%3a%5c%2f%5c%2f%29%3f%28%3f%3awww%5c.%29%3f%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3ayoutube%5c.com%5c%2fwatch%5c%3f%5b%5e%3f%5d*v%3d%7cyoutu%5c.be%5c%2f%29%29%29%28%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%29&i=%3c+href%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com%2fwatch%3fv%3dddd+http%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com%2fwatch%3fv%3dddd%22%3e+http%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com%2fwatch%3fv%3dddd).

Comment: Use an html parser to extract text nodes before, this way you avoid all html attributes. (and if you use an XPath query you can even select only text nodes that contains the string "youtu")

Comment: Actually, if you just need to *extract* the links from *plain text*, you'd better do it with HtmlAgilityPack: `public string getCleanHtml(string html)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    return HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your example works great. You are really helping me out Wiktor, thank you so much.

Comment: If it is not a one-off work, I'd rather you switch to HtmlAgilityPack or any other HTML parser. I can help you with that, too, just please explain what you are really doing. Just collecting links from a Web page that are not part of  element nodes?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I am parsing a text in an article that a user submitted on my website, turning YouTube links into their equivalent embed iframe code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when I put the regex  within a @"" string it throws a error in the character ^, anything I should escape?

Comment: I do not think you really want to go on using regex for this. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have HTMLAgilityPakck I am actually using it in my project.

Comment: This throws me an error on the ^ symbol as well as in the \. \? and \w strings: My line of code:  string pattern = @"(?<!"[^"<>]*)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:(?:(?:youtube\.com\/watch\?[^?]*v=|youtu\.be\/)))([\w-]+)";

Comment: The one thing you need to escape inside `@"..."` is the quote character itself... escape it by doubling `@""""` __not__ with backslash `@"\""` (and don't just write it un-escaped as it looks in your comment)

Comment: Working! thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: `(?<!")` will fail a match if there is no `"` *immediately before* the current location. If there must be no `"` followed with 0+ other chars before the current location, you may leverage .NET *infinite-width* lookbehind.

In this case, you might want to turn your loobehind into

```
(?<!"[^"<>]*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%22%5B%5E%22%3C%3E%5D%2A%29%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%29%3F%28%3F%3Awww%5C.%29%3F%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Ayoutube%5C.com%5C%2Fwatch%5C%3F%5B%5E%3F%5D%2Av%3D%7Cyoutu%5C.be%5C%2F%29%29%29%28%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B%29&i=%3C%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dddd%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dddd%22%3E%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dddd). Note that `[^"<>]*` matches 0+ chars other than `"`, `<` and `>`, so, the `"` will be checked only when inside an element node *if* the HTML is perfectly serialized. If it contains plain `<` or `>` inside attribute values, this approach won't work.

That is why you should think about using an appropriate HTML parser for this task, too, since you are using it already in the project. If you let know what you are trying to achieve, I will update the answer.